# Android Market Screenshots and high-res Icon

Tags: android

This is my first attempt to publish an app to Android Market and I've been working off the "Preparing to Publish Checklist" at http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

But when I tried to upload an app I discovered it wanted stuff that isn't even mentioned in the checklist. (***why aren't they on the checklist***?!)    It wants at least two screenshots in specified dimensions along with a large icon.     I don't have anything like that prepared because they're not on the checklist nor on the link on that page to "Publishing on Android Market" - http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#market

1. How do we get screenshots off our phones?   Or do people make screenshots from the Emulator?   I have screenshots on the app's website that I made from the emulator but they illustrate specific examples in the app's tutorial.   (this is an app for collecting data mostly in a medical or scientific context and it's user-configurable so the appearance of a screen is very specific to the user's configuration)
2. My icons are deliberately designed for standard Android icon resolutions (up to 72x72) - it would look ridiculous at 512x512 - Should I just make a 512x512 piece of art that's thematically related to the app's icon?

Is there some Google/Android document where they discuss these considerations?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who in Google can we contact to suggest they update their documentation?   Other than the Screenshots and large icon are there other details in the "preparing to Publish"  or "Publishing on Android Market" documents that are missing or not up to date which would be good for me (and others) to be aware of? -thanks!

Comment: It seems they have a page outlining the required graphics here: http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1078870

Comment: Now those requirements are here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirements that you mention that aren't on the list, such as the 512px icon, are recent changes.  It seems somebody forgot to update the document.

The 512px icon is for the web market, although it is actually scaled down to 256x256px currently.  It is supposed to be the same image that you use for the app icon.

You can take screenshots from a device using the DDMS tool in the SDK.  Or you can just take a screenshot of the emulator.  The two will look slightly different depending on which device you are using.  You might choose the one you think looks better or just use whichever is easier.

Comment: Just noting, you cannot take a screenshot *through* the emulator. But since it's running on your machine, you can just take a screenshot using whatever tools your Operating System gives you.